# 415 Error On Ajax jQuery Call - Spring MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-415

I am facing 415-Unsupported Media Type error on the ajax call.

I tried proposed solutions on Stackoverflow for similar questions, like adding a header to ajax call or passing dataType as json, but still the same response.

Following is my code, please guide me if I am missing anything:

**AJAX jQuery:**

```
var contentTypeJSON = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

var selectedFolderShareOrgs = [];
 $.each($("input[name='shareFolderOrg']:checked"), function(){
     var sharedOrgObj = new Object();
     sharedOrgObj.org = new Object();
     sharedOrgObj.org.id = $(this).val()
     selectedFolderShareOrgs.push(sharedOrgObj);
 });

var folderToCreate = new Object();
folderToCreate.shared = new Object();
folderToCreate.shared.name = folderName;
folderToCreate.parentId = parentFolderId;
folderToCreate.validUntil = null== folderValidUntilVal ? null : new Date(folderValidUntilVal);
folderToCreate.accessType = accessTypeVal;
folderToCreate.sharedGroupId = groupType;
folderToCreate.entityId = currentEntityId;
folderToCreate.entityType = currentEntityType;
folderToCreate.orgSharedAccess = selectedFolderShareOrgs;

// Sample JSON: "{"shared":{"name":"test folder"},"parentId":"-1","validUntil":"2020-01-31T19:59:59.000Z","accessType":"2","sharedGroupId":2,"entityId":"1","entityType":"Organization","orgSharedAccess":[]}"

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : contextPath+ "/secure/sharedFiles/createSharedFolder",
    data : JSON.stringify(folderToCreate),
    contentType : contentTypeJSON,
    success : function(data) {
        alert("uploaded!");
    },
    error : function(response, textStatus) {
        alert("error!");
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createSharedFolder")
public @ResponseBody boolean createSharedFolder(HttpServletRequest request,Principal principal,
        HttpSession session,Locale locale,ModelAndView mav, @RequestBody SharedFile folderToCreate){
    return createFolderUtil(request, principal, session, locale,mav, folderToCreate);
}
```

**Java Object:**

```
public class SharedFile implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Shared shared;
    private Documents document;
    private Chairman chairman;
    private Organization org;       
    private Sector sector;          
    private Division division;
    private Section section;
    private BigDecimal parentId;
    private Date validUntil;
    private BigDecimal accessType;      
    private BigDecimal sharedGroupId;   
    private BigDecimal entityId;    
    private String entityType;
    private BigDecimal active;
    private Set<OrganizationSharedAccess> orgSharedAccess;
    private BigDecimal status;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. assuming you are having a form id called 'uploadForm' and a submit button id called 'btn-save'.

```
     $("#btn-save").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         var folderToCreate= new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);        
         $.ajax({type : "POST",
                 url : contextPath+ "/secure/sharedFiles/createSharedFolder",
                 data : folderToCreate,
                 contentType : false,
                 processData : false,
                 success : function(data) {
                      alert("uploaded!");
                 },
                 error : function(response, textStatus) {
                   alert("error!");
             }
      });
```

in controller: 
remove `@RequestBody` just use `SharedFile folderToCreate`

Comment: By this approach, you must have the complete form to be mapped on your Object fields with name attribute. As you can see in my case the controller that has to receive the data is accepting a **Complex Object** (other objects and collections are composed inside it). In this case I won't be able to bind such fields with the form elements.